# How many elements ( values ) are in each line in a text file

Tags: c#

What to use in order to get the number of elements in each line. The example of the text file is given below. All I want to do is to get the number of elements in each line. Like the first line would have 4 elements, the second one 3 and so on.

```
1 5 4 6
2 4 6
1 9 8 7 5 3
3 2 1 1


  private static void Skaitymaz(Trikampis[] trikampiai)
  {
       string line = null;
       using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"U2.txt"))
       {
           string eilute = null;
           while (null != (eilute = reader.ReadLine()))
           {
               int[] values = eilute.Split(' ');
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Looks like assignment,

Comment: what's the problem in your code?

Comment: 1) values should be `string[]`, 2) Use `values.Length`

Comment: (forgetting about compile errors...) Why were you not able to think for yourself that the solution is just to check how many elements are in the array? That's very simple problem solving, which is a massive requirement for being a programmer. I can accept if you don't know how to count elements, but you should have already come up with the question "C# How to count elements in array" by yourself, which you would have found the answer to with a quick Google search... if you are genuinely interested in programming, then you need to get this stuff sorted out

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
   string line = null;
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"U2.txt"))
   {
       string eilute = null;
       while (null != (eilute = reader.ReadLine()))
       {
           string[] values = eilute.Split(' ');
           int noOfElement = values.Length;
       }
   }
```

Comment: urgh, that inconsistent use of `var` makes me feel ill :(

Comment: @musefan agreed with you, old habit but editing my code :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get length of the array after split,

```
values.Length
```

Comment: ``value.Length`` is fine, adding 1 would give wrong result

Comment: OP's code won't compile as `Split` doesn't return `int[]`. You may need to address that too

Answer (score 0):

Something like that (*Linq*): *read* each line, *split* it by space or, probably, tabulation and *count* the items:

```
  var numbers = File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\MyText.txt")
    .Select(line => line.Split(new Char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length);

 // Test: 4, 3, 6, 4
 Console.Write(String.Join(", ", numbers));
```